# How to fix this fitting routine (2 independent variable) using lmfit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, lmfit

I currently trying to implement a curve fitting routine with `lmfit`, although my coding skills are limited and my previous experience with `curve_fit` is not helping. Also, I have been browsing the documentation on https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html, but I still couldn't fix it.

As you can see below, I am trying to fit the following equation: `R2avg*(np.sin(thetas))**2 + ((np.sin(thetas))**2)*(phi_ex*k_ex/(k_ex**2 + omega_eff**2))`, it has 2 independent variables (`omega_eff` and `thetas`), while I'd like to fit the remaining three parameters.

```
import lmfit as lf
from lmfit import Model, Parameters
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import atan

def on_res(omega_eff, thetas, R2avg=5, k_ex=0.1, phi_ex=500):
    return R2avg*(np.sin(thetas))**2 + ((np.sin(thetas))**2)*(phi_ex*k_ex/(k_ex**2 + omega_eff**2))

model = Model(on_res,independent_vars=['omega_eff','thetas'])

model.set_param_hint('R2avg',value=5)
model.set_param_hint('k_ex',value=0.1)
model.set_param_hint('phi_ex',value=500)

carrier = 6146.53
O_1 = 5846
spin_locks = (1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000) 
delta_omega = (O_1 - carrier)

omega_eff1 = ((delta_omega**2) + (spin_locks[0]**2))**0.5
omega_eff2 = ((delta_omega**2) + (spin_locks[1]**2))**0.5
omega_eff3 = ((delta_omega**2) + (spin_locks[2]**2))**0.5
omega_eff4 = ((delta_omega**2) + (spin_locks[3]**2))**0.5
omega_eff5 = ((delta_omega**2) + (spin_locks[4]**2))**0.5

theta_rad1 = atan(spin_locks[0]/delta_omega)
theta_rad2 = atan(spin_locks[1]/delta_omega)
theta_rad3 = atan(spin_locks[2]/delta_omega)
theta_rad4 = atan(spin_locks[3]/delta_omega)
theta_rad5 = atan(spin_locks[4]/delta_omega)

x = (omega_eff1/1000, omega_eff2/1000, omega_eff3/1000, omega_eff4/1000, omega_eff5/1000)# , omega_eff6/1000)# , omega_eff7/1000)
theta = (theta_rad1, theta_rad2, theta_rad3, theta_rad4, theta_rad5)
R1rho_vals = (7.9328, 6.2642, 6.0005, 5.9972, 6.1988)
e = (0.33, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.5)

new_x = np.linspace(0, 6, 1000)
omega_eff = np.array(x, dtype=float)
thetas = np.array(theta, dtype=float)
R1rho_vals = np.array(R1rho_vals, dtype=float)

result = model.fit(R2avg, k_ex, phi_ex, thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)

plt.errorbar(x, R1rho_vals, yerr = e, fmt = ".k", markersize = 8, capsize = 3)
# plt.plot(new_x, result.best_fit, label="Two sites fast exchange")
# plt.show()
print(model.param_names)
print(model.independent_vars)
```

If I run the script as I posted, I'm getting:

```
result = model.fit(R2avg, k_ex, phi_ex, thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)
NameError: name 'R2avg' is not defined
```

Which I do not really understand. 
I did some troubleshooting, and by checking with:

`print(model.param_names)` and `print(model.independent_vars)`

It seems everything is defined appropriately.

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: You do not have a variable named `R2avg` in your code. So python does not know what you want to do when writing `model.fit(R2avg, ...)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks! How should I define it then? Simply by defining an empty list such as ```R2avg = []```?

Comment: The first argument to `.fit` should be the data you want to fit.

Comment: I defined the parameters as empty lists and moved ```omega_eff``` (experimental data I want to fit) as the first argument, although this doesn't work either. Is there any chance you could help me with a practical example? :D

Comment: You cannot fit a model to empty data. You need to have some data to fit. This data is what needs to go in the first argument.

Comment: ```omega_eff``` is defined as ```omega_eff = np.array(x, dtype=float)```, which is an array containing 5 values defined within the code (i.e., sufficient to fit the data as the wanted parameters are 3). To my understanding, I am not trying to fit a model to empty data.

Comment: Judging from the names in your code `omega_eff` is the independent data. But what are the dependent data (the y values) for those omegas?

Comment: Thanks again for replying... Now I get your point! The y's would be ```R1rho_vals```, also defined as an array of 5 values. Now, the ```.fit``` method looks like:
```result = model.fit(R1rho_vals)```, but still does not work. I am currently trying combinations looking at the documentation online. Any ideas?

Comment: The remaining arguments should be the input values of your function.

Comment: Currently trying ```result = model.fit(R1rho_vals, omega_eff, thetas, R2avg, k_ex, phi_ex)```, error arises: ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'```. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `lmfit.Model` for defining the independent parameters looks OK to be. What you are *not* doing is defining a set of Parameters to be used in the fit.

You do:

```
model = Model(on_res,independent_vars=['omega_eff','thetas'])

model.set_param_hint('R2avg',value=5)
model.set_param_hint('k_ex',value=0.1)
model.set_param_hint('phi_ex',value=500)
```

but `set_param_hint` tells the model how to make parameters, but it does not make them.   You have to do that explicitly.  In my opinion, it would be better to do

```
model = Model(on_res,independent_vars=['omega_eff','thetas'])

params = model.make_params(R2avg=5, k_ex=0.1, phi_ex=500)
```

partly because a) you *need* a Parameters object for the fit to work and b) those values aren't really part of your model (bounds on a Parameter or a constraint expression might be, but values rarely are).

Then to fit the independent (`y`) data, you want to do

```
result = model.fit(data, params, thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)
```

or (if you really insist on not creating Parameters) you can explicitly state starting values for each parameter:

```
result = model.fit(data, R2avg=5, k_ex=0.1, phi_ex=500, 
                  thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)
```

but not

```
result = model.fit(param1, param2, ..., thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff) # NO!
```

In general, explicitly using a Parameters object is preferred.

It appears (but I'm not certain) that `R1rho_vals` is the data to be fitted, so that would mean you want to do:

```
result = model.fit(R1rho_vals, params, thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)
```

To include the uncertainties (your `e`) you would do this:

```
result = model.fit(R1rho_vals, params, weights=1.0/e, 
                   thetas=thetas, omega_eff=omega_eff)
```

Then you can print and plot results:

```
print(result.fit_report())

plt.errorbar(x, R1rho_vals, yerr = e, fmt = ".k", markersize = 8, capsize = 3)
plt.plot(new_x, result.best_fit, label="Two sites fast exchange")  
plt.show()
```

Comment: First of all: thanks! I most definitely was missing some key concepts here. Now the fit works (```print(result.fit_report())``` provides sensible data), but I still have some issues plotting the graph. In one case, including ```weights=1.0/e``` I receive the error message ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'tuple'```. Is there any way I can walk around this? Looks like the does not want the division operator...
Secondly, even taking away the ```weights```, ```plt.plot``` does not work properly because of a shape mismatch with ```new_x = np.linspace```. Suggestions?

Comment: Hi again! I solved the ```weights``` issue. Working on the ```plt.plot``` problem!

Comment: yes, it is better to use numpy ndarrays instead of tuples or lists for all sequence data when fitting with lmfit.

Comment: Do you have any comments on how to display the fit with ```plt.plot()```? Using ```new_x``` I get a mismatch shape error, while using ```x``` I'm getting a very coarse profile (as expected, since I only have 5 experimental points).